# Don't query SQL string if value is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have two drop down menu's and when you select a value the value is saved in a session and passed trough AJAX to update a div. I have this working.

The reason I save the value in a session is because I need the database query to be dynamically filled (constructed). At this moment I have the following code:

```
    <?php
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $_SESSION['theme'] = $q;
        $i = $_SESSION['category'];

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(".$q.") c FROM MirrorWebProductsExpanded WHERE Subcategorie = '".$i."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "
        <a href='http://example.nl/search/'>" . $row['c'] .  "</a>";
    ?>
```

This counts all items from `$q` which is the value of the **first** drop down menu.

And `WHERE Subcategorie = '".$i."'`, `$i` is the value from the **second** drop down menu.

But, now the problem. If the **second** value is empty (I haven't selected an option from that drop down menu) the query still add's this part to the query, like:

`$query = "SELECT COUNT(".$q.") c FROM MirrorWebProductsExpanded WHERE Subcategorie = ''";`.

This makes the count from the **first** drop down menu always show `0`. Is there away to only add the `WHERE Subcategorie = '".$i."'` when the **second** drop down menu has a value?

I'm still kind of new to MySQL so please be nice...

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: you should really look into basic [injection security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Injection is my second problem. Just want the code to work. And then ill worry about the security stuff :)

Comment: In addition to what is said above this comment: I see that you are using two languages: English and another (`Subcategorie`). Try to use only one language in your code; consistent code is more maintainable.

Comment: Using prepared statement is not just about security. It will save you headaches in the future. All it takes is a random quote in random data to waste a day not understating why things are randomly failing.

Comment: _"Just want the code to work. And then ill worry about the security stuff"_ Don't build software like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query without `WHERE` clause. Then check if `$i` is not null, empty or whitespace. If so, add `WHERE` clause to your query.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(".$q.") c FROM MirrorWebProductsExpanded";
if($i != "")
    $query = $query." WHERE Subcategorie = '".$i."'";
```

Comment: I did. Thanks for the tip.